# Should I be worried about the following errors when using dask_cuda to set up client / cluster?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, dask

Here is the code I am using to setup the client / cluster:

```
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
from dask.distributed import Client

cluster = LocalCUDACluster(n_workers=6, threads_per_worker=1)
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

And here are the messages its outputting:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Nanny._on_exit() done, defined at /usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/nanny.py:440> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f05e23482d0>()]> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /usr/local/share/anaconda3/envs/rapidsai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:688]>
```

Are these warnings acceptable?

Comment: can you share your system specs ad set up?  Hard to help with what has been shared...

Comment: What is the best way to out put that

Comment: So basically, I know nothing about your machine other than you are setting up for a local CUDA cluster.  You can start with: Is this local/dedicated server or a cloud based service?  What does that configuration look like?  Which GPU(s) are you using and how much memory does it have?  That information would help us isolate possibilities to let you know if the messages are acceptable and possible mitigation.  Looking forward to hearing back

Comment: The output from the following commands would be helpful: nvidia-smi, nvidia-smi topo -m, free -m